¿Alguien me podría orientar sobre cómo quitarle este estilo a un botón en HTML?
Tengo una lista de facturas procesadas, y dependiendo de si su estado es "anulado" o "pagado", se debería mostrar el botón que pueden apreciar en la foto. Sin embargo, al mostrarse en gris, y al darle click, se despliega ese molesto outline negro que rompe con la semántica visual que busco. ¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo remover ese estilo predeterminado? Gracias de antemano.


/*Código CSS para los botones rojos:*/

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d43f3a;
}

.btn-xs,
.btn-group-xs>.btn {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/*Código CSS para el botón "no disponible":*/

.btn-anulada {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: default;
  background: #A4A4A4;
  color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
  outline: none;
}
<button class="btn-danger btn-xs">1</button>
<button class="btn-anulada">2</button>





en que navegador estás probando?

Yo no veo el "outline" ni nada en el botón gris. Aun tienes el problema??

Para quitar el estilo default al darle click sólo tienes que agregar el estilo border-style: solid a .btn
No pude replicar el border negro para el botón .btn-anulada.


/*Código CSS para los botones rojos:*/

.btn-danger {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d43f3a;
}

.btn-xs,
.btn-group-xs>.btn {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}


/*Código CSS para el botón "no disponible":*/

.btn-anulada {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: default;
  background: #A4A4A4;
  color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
  outline: none;
}
<button class="btn-danger btn-xs">1</button>
<button class="btn-anulada">2</button>



